# Should I delete my comment as very similar comments posted at the same time?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

As in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547524/housekeeping-on-uploaded-files-when-posting-information-asp-net-c-sharp-web-fo), it happens often that very similar comments are posted at the same time. Those are usually about asking `some code` from OP.

So should I delete my comment? Should other comments be deleted, but not the very first comment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general yes you should do as much as you can to keep the comment space clean. This saves time for readers and reduces clutter.

In a case such as your example where only a couple short comments and the post is from a new-ish OP to the SE network, I don't think there is much harm in leaving your comment around for a little while. The OP should see that he is getting attention from several directions and that it's not just one odd ball request for irrelevant information, he really should do something about adding more detail to his post.

If in the future you come back and he hasn't touched it and clearly doesn't plan too, having the duplicate comments is probably pointless.

**Most importantly**, if the OP does take the suggested action be sure to clean up your comments since they are obsolete and just take up space and people's time.

Answer (score 8):

If I see my comment no longer adds value, I tend to delete it. This is particularly true if it is not part of a discussion.

Comment: @moguzalp - Highly unlikely, not with the number of philosophers we have... And if the question demands a comment and none exists (as they were all deleted), someone is likely to add one :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always edit the comment to expand it and add new information or something. If the comment was posted more than five minutes ago, you can delete it then post a new one or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, sometimes using the *up arrow* near the similar previous comment (**This comment add something useful to the post**) is good.