# Is it good practice to write a "that's a great comment" in a comment for a comment reply?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

From search, I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180/168587) about issue, however it is about saying "thank you" for an answer.

Time to time, I receive great comment response to my comment: [first one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116345/should-i-delete-my-comment-as-very-similar-comments-posted-at-the-same-time#comment304045_116346) and 
[second one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127348/how-to-add-comments-in-stackoverflow#comment346393_127348)

For the first one, I just vote up and wish leave a response so for the second one I left a comment.

I am not sure both action as the comments can not be down voted, it seems either I am disagree or silent.

Is it good practice leaving comment saying "That's great comment" for the great comments, 
especially which calling me by `@mog` ?

Comment: This is a great comment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it is not.  If one appreciates the comment and wants to show it, they can **vote it up** via the arrow to the left of the comment:

[image: great comment]

The tooltip even says "**this is a great comment**".

Putting *another* comment just to say "your comment" was great is *noise* and should be flagged as "not constructive / off-topic" or "chatty" (or if you want, something custom, but the first two reasons mentioned are sufficient):

[image: flagging a comment]

Comment: @BoltClock: Sheesh.

Comment: Who exactly is this [Mr E. User](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/???/example-user) you speak of?

Comment: @Lix I hacked the HTML using Chrome's dev tools to create the mock up.  I do that normally so there's never a direct link to any *real* content if something specific isn't being talked about.  That way people don't think I'm picking on them.

Comment: I really want to say to you that that was a great comment... But I won't since it directly contradicts your post.

Answer (score 8):

No.

Comments are for *clarification of a post*, not chatty conversation.  They have no other sanctioned purpose, other than to keep "necessary noise" out of questions and answers.